# Test a bug when the testing method could be considered bad

Tags: discussion, support

**TL;DR;**
How to test bugs when the testing approach would be frowned upon?

---

---

**Context**

*Preemptive note:* I know you get [+2 when you accept an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation).

I recently posted a question and after getting an answer, even before checking it out, I miss-clicked the 'accept' button and re-clicked it to undo. In doing so, I just got +2 reputation ([yay](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x71LI.jpg)).

**The problem**

Let's *pretend* this was a bug and I was to test it. I'd have to post a new question, ask someone to answer it with gibberish so I could check the behavior, getting evidence and reliable ways to replicate the problem. I'm thinking this would cause a rain of close-votes and down-votes since, well, not-a-real-question / off-topic.

Again, this is just an example. So, is there a **recommended approach** to test this kind of possible 'bugs'?

Comment: The +2 for accept is removed again, but there is a bit of a delay. There is no bug there. So the first thing you should do is *wait for automated processes to run*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters can you read the post again, please? It has nothing to do with the reputation gain itself. It's related to controversial testing methods...

Comment: Note that I placed a **comment**, not an answer. I want to head of anyone trying to test this out and annoy a bunch of innocent users with `+15`, `-15` yo-yos because they didn't bother to read properly, as well as give you *one* guideline I can think of to head off other 'tests' where people simply didn't wait first.

Comment: Don't test. If you need to know, ask about it on Meta. 99% chance someone else already knows. If a test *really* needs to be done, it can be done with full knowledge and consent of all involved parties.

Comment: @CodyGray, hmm.. a follow up question, then: In my experience in here, people tend be _extremely_ critical (non lenient) towards the ones asking. So, asking about a bug, without it being a bug report, without reliable ways to replicate (since I wouldn't have tested it again to make sure) and the lack of example / proof (screenshots, etc), I can see people overlooking the question and pretty much trashing it, tbh. Don't you think that would happen?

Comment: Do you mean that downvotes are slung liberally on Meta? Yes, that's true. You should not worry about it, though, because there is no reputation here. People downvote things that they consider uninteresting or simply because they disagree. Obviously don't tag it [bug] if you just *suspect* that it might be a bug. Use [discussion] or [support] like you did here. Note that a downvote is not "trashing". Downvoted questions still *regularly* get good answers here and full community consideration. In fact, voting is strong evidence that there *was* full community consideration.

Comment: @CodyGray No, not votes, but comments / closes. Someone once told me how votes relate to people's opinions and not necessarily about the usefulness - and the no-reputation-loss thingy), so that's ok. I just don't see this type of questions being well-accepted, really. Again, based on what I've seen around..

Comment: Not sure about that. We get tons of questions like that. It *might* be closed as "can no longer reproduce", but then...um...that's your answer. :-) I don't know why you think it would be so poorly accepted. One thing that would probably be poorly accepted is if you flooded Meta with bunches of these and there was no evidence you had given it any thought or done any prior research yourself. But that's just par for the course, even on the main site.

Answer (score 1):

Test it [in the sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox), if possible.

Otherwise:

- Just report it on Meta to the best of your ability. You can possibly use the post you're using to report it as a way to test it as well. If you need to test by posting multiple questions, remember that you're a user and not a tester and don't do that.
- Or just ignore it.

Comment: Things like rep changes can't be tested on Meta...

Comment: @Makoto It can on [meta.se].

Comment: It's still clunky but I'll withdraw my objection.